# Bootstrap image gallery on mobile

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, blueimp, bootstrap-image-gallery

I am using the Bootstrap Image Gallery (an extension of blueimp Gallery) on a website. It works fine but displays very poorly on a mobile device. Attached is a picture of the slideshow on an iPhone 6 (you cannot pinch to zoom or anything either):  [Bootstrap image Gallery on iPhone 6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ubTq.png)

[image]

Is this normal? I would have thought a bootstrap gallery would display a bit better on a mobile device or am I doing something wrong perhaps?

Comment: Pinch zoom of link seems OK on android

Comment: The link is just a screen shot of the gallery being viewed on an iPhone, dude :)